# Names of SharePoint Product Team members

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Informative question :) 
This is not a coding/programming question.

Out of curiosity, just wanted to know the names of MSFT geeks[ SharePoint Product Team members within MS] who actually coded the components/modules in SharePoint product.

Comment: how to make this Q as type of community-wiki

Comment: What answer would you get if you asked Volkswagen who built your New Beetle?

Comment: Thanks Danny! I was going through the SP 2016 Bill Baer's SP Saturday Redmond Keynote in youtube,today. He talked about the evolution from 2001 to 2016 including MS Managed Services. So just thought about those Geeks,Gurus who were behind this giant/monster product/platform. :-) hence posted this Q ...

Comment: If you want to watch videos by MVPs, check out https://www.unityconnect.com/

Answer (score 1):

A little bit dated, but you will find some names in these blog articles [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/).

Some of them may not be involved with SharePoint anymore, but it's worth looking in to.

A more updated blog can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/). You may find some names in there too.

Poking around [here](https://blogs.office.com/feed/?filter-audience=dev) might land you a few other names aswell :)

Comment: You wil find everyone is called "Product Manager".. those are not the workers who wrote all those lines of code.